# "Prime or not" program

Tags: c++, primes

I am stuck on this really simple program in C++, where I let the user know the number she/he have entered is prime or not, but, because of some reason, everything works fine during the first loop but things go fishy during the second. I would be more than happy if anyone could help ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int number1 = 5;
    int number;
    int a = 0;

    while (number1 == 5)
    {
        int b = 1;
        cout << "Enter your number and we'll tell you if it's prime or not: ";
        cin >> number;

        while (a <= number)
        {
            a++;
            if (number % a == 0)
                b++;
        }

        if (b == 3)
            cout << "Your number is prime" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Your number is not prime" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "goes fishy".

Comment: That means if you enter a prime in the following loops then it prints "it is not prime", that's what he means with fishy.

Answer (score 2):

The are several problems with your program.

The first one is that the loop starting with statement

```
while (number1 == 5)
```

is infinite because `number1` is not changed within the loop.

The second one is that you must always initialize variable `a`  to zero within the loop. And it should be defined also within the loop because it is not used outside the loop. The same is valid for variable `number`.

Take into account that a number is prime if it is divisble by 1 and itself (except number 1). So I would initially set variable `b` to zero and compare it with 2. It is more clear than to compare it with 3.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your number and we'll tell you if it's prime or not (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int number = 0;
        std::cin >> number;

        if ( number == 0 ) break;

        unsigned int n = 0;
        unsigned int divisor = 0;

        while ( divisor++ < number )
        {
            if ( number % divisor == 0 ) n++;
        }

        if ( n == 2 )
            std::cout << "Your number is prime" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Your number is not prime" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to reinit `a` to `0` before the inner while.

This makes it work. However, I suggest you take time to learn to code. It does not look educated.

Also your program won't exit. Not sure what your intention is, but you could omit the `number1` variable and simply use `while(1)` (considering your code stands as is; probably you are at the beginning of your development though, so it depends).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    int number1 = 5;
    int number;


    int a = 0;

    while (number1 == 5)
    {
        int b = 1;
        cout << "Enter your number and we'll tell you if it's prime or not: ";
        cin >> number;

        a = 0;  <-- Reset to 0 would make it work
        while (a <= number)
        {

            a++;

            if (number % a == 0)
                b++;


        }

        if (b == 3)
            cout << "Your number is prime" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Your number is not prime" << endl;
    }
}
```

P.S.: You are new to StackOverflow. So you likely take the answer and get away. Please consider accepting the answer. It's a respectful practice when it solved your issue.

Comment: Consider moving the declaration of `a` inside the while loop, instead of just adding the rest.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I simply copied the code. The variable "a" needed to be reset, not more. I think it is easier for the OP, since I believe he is a beginner (looks like Harry Potter too).

Comment: Remove `int a=0` then change your code to `int a = 0;  // <-- Reset to 0 would make it work`

Comment: Is there a reason do so? Isn't it less efficient then? I think it is better to declare once and the use the var, instead of declaring it every time.

Comment: I guess it's because if you do not need the variable anywhere else in your code there is no need for it to be declared in main's scope.

Comment: That makes sense. It's just a simple program though.